# Declaring several appenders in log4j2.properties file

Tags: java, log4j2

In the same **log4j2.properties** file I want to declare several appenders, lets say ‘**XXX**’ and ‘**YYY**’.

The problem is that with this configuration:

```
#GENERIC
rootLogger.level = DEBUG
rootLogger.appenderRefs = XXX, YYY
appenders = XXX, YYY
loggers = XXX, YYY

#XXX
rootLogger.appenderRef.XXX.ref = XXX
logger.XXX.name = XXX
logger.XXX.level = DEBUG
property.XXX.filename = C:/logs/XXX.log
appender.XXX.type = RollingFile
appender.XXX.name = XXX
appender.XXX.fileName = ${XXX.filename}
appender.XXX.filePattern = ${XXX.filename}.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}
appender.XXX.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.XXX.layout.pattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %c{1} [%p] %m%n
appender.XXX.policies.type = Policies
appender.XXX.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.XXX.policies.time.interval = 1

#YYY
rootLogger.appenderRef.YYY.ref = YYY
logger.YYY.name = YYY
logger.YYY.level = DEBUG
property.YYY.filename = C:/logs/YYY.log
appender.YYY.type = RollingFile
appender.YYY.name = YYY
appender.YYY.fileName = ${YYY.filename}
appender.YYY.filePattern = ${YYY.filename}.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}
appender.YYY.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.YYY.layout.pattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %c{1} [%p] %m%n
appender.YYY.policies.type = Policies
appender.YYY.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.YYY.policies.time.interval = 1
```

Using this, the log message is traced into **XXX.log** file and also to **YYY.log** file

```
Logger log = Logger.getLogger(“XXX”);
log.info("Some info to the log”);
```

Does somebody know what I am doing wrong?
What is the minimum configuration required, considering I need to declare a lot of appenders in the same properties file?

Comment: You are adding all appenders to `rootLogger`, instead of `logger.XXX` and `logger.YYY`.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't get it. I have kept trying various things and it doesn't work. Can you be more explicit? Thanks

Comment: Instead of `rootLogger.appenderRef.XXX.ref=XXX` use `logger.XXX.appenderRef.XXX.ref=XXX`.

Comment: Thanks! It already works. I'm going to put it as it remains below. (However I still see it very verbose, I don't know if it could be simplified)

Answer (score 0):

```
#GENERIC
rootLogger.level = DEBUG
rootLogger.appenderRefs = XXX
appenders = XXX, YYY
loggers = XXX, YYY

#XXX
logger.XXX.appenderRef.XXX.ref=XXX
logger.XXX.name = XXX
logger.XXX.level = DEBUG
property.XXX.filename = C:/logs/XXX.log
appender.XXX.type = RollingFile
appender.XXX.name = XXX
appender.XXX.fileName = ${XXX.filename}
appender.XXX.filePattern = ${XXX.filename}.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}
appender.XXX.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.XXX.layout.pattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %c{1} [%p] %m%n
appender.XXX.policies.type = Policies
appender.XXX.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.XXX.policies.time.interval = 1

#YYY
logger.YYY.appenderRef.YYY.ref = YYY
logger.YYY.name = YYY
logger.YYY.level = DEBUG
property.YYY.filename = C:/logs/YYY.log
appender.YYY.type = RollingFile
appender.YYY.name = YYY
appender.YYY.fileName = ${YYY.filename}
appender.YYY.filePattern = ${YYY.filename}.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}
appender.YYY.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.YYY.layout.pattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %c{1} [%p] %m%n
appender.YYY.policies.type = Policies
appender.YYY.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.YYY.policies.time.interval = 1
```

Comment: You should probably only include the differences in the configuration files in your answer. Remark also that explicitly listing the ids of the appenders (`appenders = XXX, YYY`), loggers and appenderRefs is not necessary. If you omit those lines, all the elements present will be used.

Comment: After reading this I am considering using xml format: "I recommend you to consider moving to xml format. Most of examples in the log4j2 documentation are for xml configuration format. In case of xml, loggers configuration is much compact"

Comment: The properties configuration has lots of useless identifiers, e.g. in `appender.XXX.policies.time.interval` you can replace `XXX`, `policies` and `time` with anything else (as long as you modify the related properties).

Comment: Could you please post definitive simplified version?

Comment: Your version is already simplified. Does replacing `XXX` with `X` and `policies` with `p` count as simplification?

Comment: You said: "The properties configuration has lots of useless identifiers". ¿could you post suggested version without useless identifiers? (I only want two separate appenders XXX and YYY that write logs to XXX.log and YYY.log respectively)

Comment: Sorry, I said _"useless"_, but I meant _"meaningless"_. They are **necessary** for the configuration to work, but the exact identifier you use does not matter. The XML format does not require those `XXX`, `policies`, etc.

Comment: Finally, given your knowledge of log4j2, I would like to ask you if you can post what the log4j2.properties file would look like incorporating the minimum configuration lines necessary for log records from other appenders other than XXX and YYY to be saved in an 'OTHERS.log' file

Answer (score 0):

Simplified version:

```
#GENERIC
rootLogger.level = DEBUG

#XXX
logger.XXX.appenderRef.XXX.ref=XXX
logger.XXX.name = XXX
logger.XXX.level = DEBUG
property.XXX.filename = C:/logs/XXX.log
appender.XXX.type = RollingFile
appender.XXX.name = XXX
appender.XXX.fileName = ${XXX.filename}
appender.XXX.filePattern = ${XXX.filename}.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}
appender.XXX.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.XXX.layout.pattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %c{1} [%p] %m%n
appender.XXX.policies.type = Policies
appender.XXX.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.XXX.policies.time.interval = 1

#YYY
logger.YYY.appenderRef.YYY.ref = YYY
logger.YYY.name = YYY
logger.YYY.level = DEBUG
property.YYY.filename = C:/logs/YYY.log
appender.YYY.type = RollingFile
appender.YYY.name = YYY
appender.YYY.fileName = ${YYY.filename}
appender.YYY.filePattern = ${YYY.filename}.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}
appender.YYY.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.YYY.layout.pattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %c{1} [%p] %m%n
appender.YYY.policies.type = Policies
appender.YYY.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.YYY.policies.time.interval = 1
```